# Wordpress orderby date not working

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-order-by

Somehow this doesn't work on my server

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

It works in the local development environment but not live...

How could this be, posts are always sorted oldest to newest instead

Comment: the query didn't get anything ?

Comment: @Awea it get's the normal posts but ASC or DESC doesn't have any effect in production. It's always ASC what is weared because default already is DESC

Comment: @Martin Hohenberg development and live both 3.2.1 and plugins are the same local and in production

Comment: @spankmaster79 it's very strange, what's happen if you use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts instead of WP_Query ?

Comment: @Awea doesn't work also what works is `$sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts 
WHERE post_type = 'news' 
AND post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 4"` and then `$wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to replace date with post_date.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Confirm the name of db column is `date`, or something other like `post_date`.

Comment: zuzuleinen was earlier so he get's the correct answer, yours is correct too